# KML support in Google Earth 6.2.1.6014 for mobile

Tags: ios, kml, google-earth

The latest version of Earth for iOS doesn't support the normal KML Description tags for the placemark balloons. Is there a resource to find out how to populate these balloons? It is possible as some of the examples on the Google Earth gallery have working balloons...

Comment: Descriptions should display appropriately - can you provide a link to an example KML that does not work as you expect?

Comment: Sure, thanks. This link: www.cubelease.com/test.kml    This placemark opens a balloon with text in the description field, works fine in the desktop version but a blank balloon appears in the latest mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a Google account to view the link but [Google Forum Topic](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/earth/empty%2420ballons/earth/i_MpboxRyZY/0cOIjasHlb0J). Essentially, they know of the issue and are working to resolve it. The only work-around for now is to upload the kml/kmz to mymaps. Funny, how it works great on Android ;-P

Answer (score 0):

for exactly the same issue with the description balloons on placemarks with ios5.  Have an iphone with earlier ios and it works ok

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a KML file with `NetworkLink` tag referring to your ***remote*** KML file and download the file.
Then description rendering works well even on iOS5.
`Remote`, which means a file places at a server like `http://example.com/sample.kml`, is important. Local files like a file in a .kmz file don't work currently.